# Navigating Text...Is there a way to go back and/or forward N characters or jump to next/previous non-alphanumeric character?

Tags: text-processing, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, text, keyboard-event

I'm talking in terms of keyboard navigation shortcuts, that would apply to any text box/editor/etc...Sometimes I'd like to just have a faster means of jumping to a particular location in a string, but instead all I appear to have is ctrl+left/right arrows to jump between strings and sometimes spaces and non-alpanumeric characters can be used as dividers but not all of them get recognized, and all of this makes editing long strings and text in general very spoon expensive. Is it not even possible to just have a customized shortcut that makes the blinking line jump, say, five characters/steps backwards/forwards, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Every editor is different.
So no, there is no method that would work everywhere.

But if you want that functionality: use vim.

In command mode you can use `:123` to jump to line 123, `/something` to search for something, and so one. See the [docs](https://www.vim.org/docs.php)

Comment: ...not even for URL bars? That should've been my prime example, actually...